# How to declare build-time dependencies without breaking other packages?

Tags: python, setuptools

I ran into a problem when installing a package which depended on `python-daemon`.  I ultimately traced it to the latest version of the package `python-daemon` (2.0.3) released yesterday.  Testing in a virtual environment on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and issuing the following commands:

```
(venv) $ pip list
argparse (1.2.1)
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (3.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
(venv) $ pip install redis
 ... works fine ....
(venv) $ pip install python-daemon
 ...
 snip
 ...   
 File "/home/pwj/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2147, in load

['__name__'])

ImportError: No module named version

(venv)02:15 PM tmp$ pip list
argparse (1.2.1)
lockfile (0.10.2)
pip (1.5.6)
python-daemon (2.0.3)
setuptools (3.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

So the install of `python-daemon` seemed to work but something affected `pip` or `setuptools` because other packages (`celery`, `flask`), I try to install with pip after this gives me the same traceback:

```
 ...
 snip
 ...   

 File "/home/pwj/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2147, in load

['__name__'])

ImportError: No module named version
```

If I uninstall python-daemon with pip things again and packages that weren't installing now install fine.  Has anyone else come across this or something similar with a different project?  My solution was to pip install the previous version

```
(venv) $ pip install python-daemon==2.0.2
... works ...
```

but was wondering what might be causing such an error.

Comment: As of python-daemon version 2.0.4 this issue is resolved, big thanks to python-daemon developer(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This behaviour is corrected in python-daemon version 2.0.4 and later.)

There are two sides to this:

- Setuptools assumes it is the centre of everything.
- Version 2.0.3 of python-daemon doesn't take that into account.

A more detailed explanation: There is some complex code using Docutils involved in the python-daemon *build* process, that isn't needed after install and isn't part of the library code.

It's too complex to leave in the un-importable (and therefore not-unit-testable) `setup.py`, so that build code is shunted to a separate testable module, `version` (in the file `version.py`), which itself uses Docutils.

But then the `setup.py` has a circular dependency: How to import `version`, when Docutils isn't yet installed? How to use Setuptools to ensure Docutils is installed, when running `setup.py` to completion will need `version`? All the feasible solutions are ugly and confusing.

The approach taken in ‘python-daemon’ 2.0.3 is to declare Docutils required for setup, and declare a [Setuptools entry point](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#entry-points) for the work that needs `version`. That way `setup.py` gets to install Docutils before any of the entry points that will use `version`.

But now we come to the first point, that Setuptools arrogates itself as the centre of everything. By declaring an entry point, `setup.py` has modified *every* Setuptools action thereafter, and every package will fail if it can't find the entry points. And, since most of them don't have `version` or the specified functions in that module, they crash Setuptools.

What is essentially a bug to be fixed, reveals a poorly-understood corner case in Setuptools. So I'm voting your question up.

There doesn't seem to be a good solution to this: having modules available for `setup.py` but ensuring requirements are met first. Setuptools assumes it is the only build system needed to satisfy all dependencies for everything, and when that assumption fails it's very difficult to get around.

Thanks to the [Python Packaging Authority](http://pypa.io/) folks, and the [`distutils-sig` forum](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/distutils-sig), for explaining this to me.

Comment: no temporarily/alternative solution to install python-daemon?

Comment: @Ali   As of python-daemon version 2.0.4 this issue is resolved

Comment: @bignose I assume you're the dev. Something similar is happening with pip 6.1.1 and python-daemon==2.0.5: venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:291: UserWarning: The version specified (u'UNKNOWN') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details.
  "details." % self.metadata.version
error: The 'python-daemon==2.0.5' distribution was not found and is required by ...

Comment: @bignose Also if you are the dev please update the project page on pypi - the linked page (debian.org) lists 1.5.5 as the most recent version making me think it's dead. Thanks.

Comment: the answer is nonsense,

entrypoints are pretty much a feature intended for *installed* packages,

Comment: Some points of correction: First, setup.py could be importable ([ref](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/jaraco.develop/src/0220745cefe2266d4d9ffabe693f9b329498d061/setup.py?at=default)). Second, the entry_point used was egg_info.writers; python-daemon was specifically hooking into setuptools' own behavior (not an issue with entry points in general). Third, Setuptools does not assume it is the center of everything, but is built on the model presented by the stdlib (distutils). Finally, Setuptools welcomes enthusiastic, loving contributors. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the writeup.